# How can I turn listings on for just one folder in my webapps, as opposed to every folder

Tags: java, tomcat, directory-listing

At the moment I have listings enabled(see code below) which means everyfolder is affected. how can i make it so that only webapps/myProject/myFolder is listable?

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I have looked at [this document](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html#dir) but i do not understand it. can someone help please.

**edit: my local web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd"[]>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID">
  <display-name>Project1</display-name>
  <description>Project1</description>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>EnableSessionPersistency</param-name>
    <param-value>False</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>DataDirectory</param-name>
    <param-value>App_Data</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.aspx</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>Mainsoft.Web.SessionState.SessionListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>VmwIncludeHelperServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.IncludeHelperServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>GhDynamicHttpServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>XmlDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>XmlContentTypeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>XmlDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rdTemplate/rdAjax/rdAjax.aspx</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/aspnetconfig</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/aspnetconfig/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/assemblies/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.mdf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.lck</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.properties</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.dat</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ctrl</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.aspx</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.asmx</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ashx</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.invoke</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.soap</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.rem</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.axd</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.master</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.resource</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.skin</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.browser</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.sitemap</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.webinfo</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.resx</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.asax</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ascx</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.config</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.Config</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.cs</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.vb</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.csproj</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.vbproj</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.licx</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwDynamicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.dll</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VmwIncludeHelperServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servletincludehelper</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Default.aspx</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying the `web.xml` under `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`, put the below configuration in your local `web.xml`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

...

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/to/listabledir</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The key here is the line `<url-pattern>/path/to/listabledir</url-pattern>`.

The [Tomcat Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q12) should give you some reference.

Comment: my web.xml file looks different (added to the original message) can you show me where to add them please.

Comment: Yes, you've to add them manually. Take a look some of the tomcat's web.xml. The examples web app should help.

Comment: i see that there are many <servlet> tags now. do i have to add it to each one of them?

Comment: No, just paste the above snippet (excluding the ...) between the last `</servlet>` and the first `<servlet-mapping>` tags.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. everything returns 404 error now. including default file

Comment: Please post the complete web.xml

Comment: @user521180 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2525/discussion-between-adarshr-and-user521180)

Comment: I have resolved this issue now. the problem was the name of the servlet. I changed it from Default to Listing and it works now. thanks again